# foreach loop doesnt iterate through everything if 1 or 2 elements

Tags: php

the foreach loop isnt working as expected for me if there is one or two elemtns in an array.

```
$min = INF;
$max = -INF;

foreach ($mainResponse['chart'] as $elem) {
  if ($elem['soldPrice'] > $max) {
      $max = $elem['soldPrice'];
      $maxDate = $elem['dateSold'];
  } elseif ($elem['soldPrice'] < $min) {
      $min = $elem['soldPrice'];
      $minDate = $elem['dateSold'];
  }
}
```

Here is the example for the array.

```
"chart":[{"soldPrice":780,"dateSold":"08\/30\/2020"},{"soldPrice":999.99,"dateSold":"08\/30\/2020"}]
```

Nothing shows up for me when I try to handle this. Why is the foreach loop not looping through it?

This is what I would get...

```
"minDate":null,"maxDate":"08\/30\/2020","maxPrice":"999.99","minPrice":"inf"
```

For the two, I would expect it to determine the correct min/max as well as the date. This works fine if there are 3 or more.

Comment: I would try switching from `elseif` to just `if` (the fact that works for 3 is just a case, try with 3 product ordered by `soldPrice` and you will see that you have the same problem )

Comment: `var_dump($mainResponse)` to make sure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: @Berto99 that was the meal ticket! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `soldPrice` is always greater than `$max`, in every case. So on every iteration of the loop it will always enter the first `if` block and never enter the `elseif` block, and so will simply overwrite `$max` and `$maxPrice` every time.

The fact it worked with 3 items in the array is probably just coincidence - you didn't show the sample, but it seems certain that the soldPrice was lower in the last item.

You can remedy this quite easily by changing

```
elseif ($elem['soldPrice'] < $min) {
```

to

```
if ($elem['soldPrice'] < $min) {
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aaeb71e0d95ecf4065d9c1a6fb99e9fb241eca9e

2nd demo with extra data items, to show it more effectively: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc326dd62f0fae31eec2126fb758283e23e60177